# Which one is correct? A B or C?

Tags: grammar, word-difference, phrasal-verbs, exam-questions

24.Tom thought he would get ______ his obsession with computers and become a lawyer like his father.
     A. over                       B. in                         C. out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over is the only one that makes sense.

To 'get over' something is to come to terms with it, or move on from it.  E.g. one might get over a romantic relationship ending.  To get over one's obsession is to no longer suffer that obsession.